# BeautifulSoup: Iterating a list of elements and extracting text by class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to play with Python and improve some scraping skills.

The following code should extract author and affiliation information from a scientific article:

```py
def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    target = soup.find_all("span")
    
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Autor", "Afiliacao"])
        for tar in target:
            name = tar.find("span", attrs={'name': True})
            print(name)
            afiliacao = tar.find(class_='affiliation')
            
            writer.writerow([name, afiliacao])


main("https://rpmgf.pt/ojs/index.php/rpmgf/article/view/13494")
```

However, I can only get `None` as results.

However, if I make something in the way of

```py
texto_soup = BeautifulSoup(texto_artigo.content,"lxml")
  autores = texto_soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'name'})
  afiliacao=  texto_soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'affiliation'})
  for a, b in zip(autores, afiliacao):
    print(a.text+b.text)
```

it works (still need to strip results from extra white spaces and extra line breaks).
But... I don't understand why the first example doesn't work.

As a bonus: how to solve the missing data problem in the second example? I know I can't use `zip_longest` but in that case I get an error in missing elements because those don't have a `.text` property.

Comment: _I can only get "None" as results_ This does not tell us enough detail.  Please show the actual csv file output.

Comment: The two examples are doing different things, so it makes perfect sense that you would get different results.  Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: In the markup, what is the _actual_ element you're looking for? Please paste a sample of the HTML.

Comment: @JohnGordon I get this Autor,Afiliacao
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,

Comment: @Reinderien the article at [link](https://rpmgf.pt/ojs/index.php/rpmgf/article/view/13494); the first span is /html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/article/div/div[1]/section[1]/ul/li[1]/span[1] and the second ins /html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/article/div/div[1]/section[1]/ul/li[1]/span[2] and so on. All articles have at least one "author" but not all have affiliation. I tried to first select all 'span' tags and then select only the ones with the class i'm interessed on.

Comment: @JohnGordon in the first example I first select  all 'span' tags and then select only the ones with the class i'm interessed on. In the second example I bypass the first step and go rirectly to the 'span' tag I'm interested identified by their class. But why the first example doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strain to the `section`, then select on `class_`:

```py
from typing import Iterator

import bs4
from requests import Session


STRAINER = bs4.SoupStrainer(name='section', class_='item authors')


def fetch_authors(session: Session, article: int) -> bs4.ResultSet:
    with session.get(
        url=f'https://rpmgf.pt/ojs/index.php/rpmgf/article/view/{article}',
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        dom = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=resp.text, parse_only=STRAINER, features='lxml')
    return dom.find_all(name='span', class_='name')


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        for author_tag in fetch_authors(session=session, article=13494):
            print(author_tag.text.strip())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Maria João Gonçalves
Clara Fonseca
Inês Pintalhão
Rodrigo Costa
Ana Calafate
Manuel Henriques
```

Or if you also care about affiliation:

```py
from typing import Iterator

import bs4
from requests import Session


STRAINER = bs4.SoupStrainer(name='section', class_='item authors')


def fetch_authors(session: Session, article: int) -> Iterator[tuple[str, str | None]]:
    with session.get(
        url=f'https://rpmgf.pt/ojs/index.php/rpmgf/article/view/{article}',
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        dom = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=resp.text, parse_only=STRAINER)  # , features='lxml')

    for name in dom.find_all(name='span', class_='name'):
        # Search through siblings for a matching affiliation tag
        for affiliation in name.find_next_siblings(name='span'):
            name_str = name.text.strip()
            class_ = affiliation.attrs.get('class', ())[0]
            if class_ == 'affiliation':
                # If we've found an affiliation class on the soonest span sibling, use it
                yield name_str, affiliation.text.strip()
                break
            elif class_ == 'name':
                # If we've encountered the next name, there is no affiliation.
                yield name_str, None
                break
        else:
            # If there are no span siblings, there is no affiliation.
            yield name.text.strip(), None


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        print('An article with some authors missing affiliation:')
        for name, affiliation in fetch_authors(session=session, article=13545):
            print(f'{name} ({affiliation})')
        print()

        print('An article with authors all having affiliation:')
        for name, affiliation in fetch_authors(session=session, article=13494):
            print(f'{name} ({affiliation})')
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
An article with some authors missing affiliation:
Andreia Oliveira (Médica)
Rita Paraíso (None)
Paola Lobão (None)
Vanessa Guerreiro (None)

An article with authors all having affiliation:
Maria João Gonçalves (USF Garcia de Orta)
Clara Fonseca (Assistente Graduada de Medicina Geral e Familiar na USF Garcia de Orta, ACeS Porto Ocidental)
Inês Pintalhão (Assistente de Medicina Geral e Familiar da USF Garcia de Orta, ACes Porto Ocidental)
Rodrigo Costa (Interno de Formação Específica de Medicina Geral e Familiar da USF Garcia de Orta, ACeS Porto Ocidental)
Ana Calafate (Assistente de Medicina Geral e Familiar da USF Garcia de Orta, ACeS Porto Ocidental)
Manuel Henriques (Assistente de Medicina Geral e Familiar da USF Garcia de Orta, ACeS Porto Ocidental)
```

Comment: Of course it works, but your solution is well above my present knowledge. 

STRAINER = bs4.SoupStrainer(name='section', class_='item authors')
# is the only advantage in using SoupStrainer parsing speed later on?

def fetch_authors(session: Session, article: int) -> tuple[str, str | None]:
# tuple[str, str | None] means that any of the 'str' can be 'None' or just the last one?
resp.raise_for_status()
# so this allow to get an error code if the page is not found; so can I assume as optional?

Comment: dom = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=resp.text, parse_only=STRAINER)  # , features='lxml')
# question here: what is 'markup=resp.text'; I can't find any explanation about its usage like that
yield name.text.strip(), None
# I don't quite understand 'yield' but that's ok: I got time to learn; but why the 'name_str' if we find affiliation but 'name_str.text.strip()' if we don't?

Comment: Let's please continue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256855/beautifulsoup-iterating-a-list-of-elements-and-extracting-text-by-class

Comment: Not enough reputation ate the moment. But I'll get there.